# Clipboard.SetImage doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, clipboard

I'm trying to download image from a URL and set it to the Clipboard (WPF). I can paste image to Paint but not to a local directory.

Here is my codes downloading and setting to clipboard:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(urlImg); // urlImg  - url of image
var response = request.GetResponse();
var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
var bitmap2 = new Bitmap(responseStream);

var orgimg = LoadBitmap2(bitmap2); // converting to BitmapSource
Clipboard.SetImage(orgimg);
```

Comment: What is your proble and what is the content of urlImg?

Comment: urlImg is a simple url of image,Problem is i couldn't paste image to local directory but when i tried to paste to Paint it's pasted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you cut/copy and paste an image to the file system only the path(s) are in the clipboard data.

If you want to 'paste' a downloaded image to a directory you'll need to emulate that behaviour:

1. Write the downloaded image to a temp directory
2. Set up the clipboard with the appropriate paste data (see [DataFormats.FileDrop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dataformats.filedrop(v=vs.110).aspx))
3. Make sure the mode is set to 'cut' so that the image isn't left in the temp location

**Example**

```
string url = "http://example.com/images/someimage.jpeg";
var img = GetImageFromUrl(url);

//write the image to a temporary location (todo: purge it later)
var tmpFilePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetFileName(url));
img.Save(tmpFilePath);

//group image(s)
var imgCollection = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();
imgCollection.Add(tmpFilePath);

//changing the drop affect to 'move' from the temp location
byte[] moveEffect = new byte[] { 2, 0, 0, 0 };
MemoryStream dropEffect = new MemoryStream();
dropEffect.Write(moveEffect, 0, moveEffect.Length);

//set up our clipboard data
DataObject data = new DataObject();
data.SetFileDropList(imgCollection);
data.SetData("Preferred DropEffect", dropEffect);

//push it all to the clipboard
Clipboard.Clear();
Clipboard.SetDataObject(data, true);
```

Where `GetImageFromUrl()` is:

```
private System.Drawing.Image GetImageFromUrl(string url)
{
    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

    using (HttpWebResponse httpWebReponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        using (Stream stream = httpWebReponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
            return System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: You'll need to add a reference to `System.Drawing` for the `Image` class. I'm sure there's an alternative in the WPF spaces.

**Further Reading**

- [MSDN System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [How the clipboard works, pt 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2012/03/16/how-the-clipboard-works-part-1.aspx)
- [How the clipboard works, pt 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2012/03/29/how-the-clipboard-works-part-2.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for quick reply,it's work but i couldn't past it twice,i mean when i tried second time to paste same image it didn't paste.

Comment: If you want to paste multiple times you'll need to use 'copy' instead of 'cut'. Try removing `data.SetData("Preferred DropEffect", dropEffect);` and the associated code which set's the 'cut' drop effect. IMPORTANT: You should still remove the downloaded images from the tmpFilePath after the user is done copying it to places.

Comment: How i can save tmpFilePath and delete these file when application closing or is there any solution to do it? @kyle